# Is it ethical to be a mock juror?

Tags: ethics

I enjoyed being a mock juror and got paid for my time.  It was a couple weeks before the trial.  The Plaintiff laid out their case and I explained in detail everything they should not say to the real jury because it hurt their case.

Based on the facts they presented, I felt very strongly that they were not entitled to recover from the Defendant.  I feel like I perverted the course of justice by telling them which facts they should not disclose to the jury.

I feel like the type of case and its outcome shouldn't matter to this question, but I know someone will ask.  Perhaps think about the question before reading the spoiler and see if your answer changes.

> Car vs truck.  Plaintiff is now a quadriplegic.  Case was settled before the scheduled jury trial.

Comment: What they should and should not say to the real jury is largely prescribed by law, *how* they say it is another matter. But even if a mock juror helps with achieving a desired result, presenting the best legally possible case is a premise of the adversarial system in courts. No matter how one feels about what the outcome "should" be, helping a side to prepare a better presentation is, in principle, a good thing. Of course, in reality everything is not so clear cut, something legal may, nonetheless, be untoward, the two sides may not have equal resources, and this tips the balance unfairly, etc

Comment: Is it ethical to be a criminal defense lawyer, who generally advocates for lesser punishment for the criminal? I guess it depends on your concept of justice. Is it up to the system to enact justice i.e. due process of law, or is it up to everyone, including you?